# Tkinter OptionMenu subheaders

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I am wondering if it is possible to add subheaders in OptionMenu on Python3 Tkinter project.
Like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *disabled* menu item to **simulate** the sub-header effect.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.StringVar()
optmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var1, None)
optmenu.pack()

menu_items = {
    'armscii8': ('armscii8_bin', 'armscii8_general_ci'),
    'ascii': ('ascii_bin', 'ascii_general_ci')
}

menu = optmenu['menu']
menu.delete(0)
menu.config(disabledforeground='black')
bgcolor = menu.cget('bg')
for key, items in menu_items.items():
    menu.add_command(label=key, state='disabled', font=(None,10,'bold'), activebackground=bgcolor)
    for m in items:
        menu.add_command(label='      '+m, command=tk._setit(var1, m, None))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]